# Hashmap JSON Sum of Same Key

Tags: android, hashmap

Good Day, I have been going through almost every post of how to sum the values of HashMaps that is using the same key, most, if not all is referring to two Hashmaps and then merging.

What I need to achieve is the following:
I have a HashMap that I have populated from a JSON response and the data within the hashmap looks like the following:

```
String Key: House1
String Value: 500
String Key: House1
String Value: 5000
String Key: House2
String Value: 200
String Key: House1
String Value: 500
String Key: House2
String Value: 500
```

I want to populate a List to only show the sum of all the values, thus in the above example the list should only have the below:

```
String Key: House1
String Value: 6000
String Key: House2
String Value: 700
```

When I populate a ListView I can see that all the data is populated correctly in the Hashmap.

Any assistance with this query would be appreciated.

Thank You,
Kind Regards

Comment: `House2 String Value: 400` mistake ? looks like it would be 700 ?

Comment: Correct @AliAhmed, I will fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap doesnt allow multiple values for single key. Hashmap overwrites that key if there is same key like below.

```
map.put("House1","500");
map.put("House1","5000");
```

Output

```
key: value
House1: 5000
```

Comment: The issue that I am facing is that I am using a String as a Key, in this example it would be house1 but the JSON does also include it's own ID that is incremental, thus each entry is seen as a new one, what I want to do is to use the populated hashmap, get all the populated strings of house1 and then sum all the values and only create a one line with the values in a ArrayList. I hope this makes sense. - Thank You

Comment: the current standard for JSON published by the Internet Engineering Task Force (IETF), states "The names within an object SHOULD be unique" https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159

Answer (score 0):

Map doesn't allow Same keys. But you can do some thing like this..

THis will solve your problem

```
private void calc(HashMap<String, Integer> map, String key, Integer value) {
    if (map.containsKey(key)) { //Key already exist in Hashmap

        Integer val = map.get(key); // get the value of key
        val = val + value; // adding new value and old value
        map.put(key, val); //Storing sum of values
    }else {
        map.put(key, value);
    }
```

I'm passing the Hashmap, key and value to this function, then check in Hashmap if that key exist or not. if it exist, i get its value and add the new value in it, so at the end you get the sum

Comment: I have found a way using Hashmap and ArrayList, I will show you the code below: - Thank you all for the suggestions :)

if(StringKey.equals(StringKey)){

totalpol += Integer.parseInt(HouseVal);

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
 map.put(TAG_StringKey, StringKey);
map.put("Total", String.valueOf(totalpol));
final List<HashMap> list = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
list.add(map);

Gives me the one lines required :)